# Custom Control in DataGrid Template

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I created a datagrid. I would like to include a custom control in a `DataTemplate` (CLightSystem). The control works outside of the data grid. In the data grid, the "Value" property is always empty, although `StatusDrawing` is not empty. What could be the reason for this?

```
 <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5" 
                      BorderThickness="3"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding CncCollectionM12}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      CanUserAddRows="False"
                      IsReadOnly="True"
                      FontSize="16"
                      Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGrid}">

                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="M12" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="LIGHT SYSTEM"></TextBlock>
                                    <components:CLightSystem Value="{Binding StatusDrawing}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

This is the class from the custom control:

```
  public class CLightSystem : Control
    {
        private Ellipse redLight;
        private Ellipse orangeLight;
        private Ellipse greenLight;


        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Value", typeof(string), typeof(CLightSystem), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

        public string Value
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
        }

        static CLightSystem()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CLightSystem), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CLightSystem)));
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            redLight = Template.FindName("ERedLight", this) as Ellipse;
            orangeLight = Template.FindName("EOrangeLight", this) as Ellipse;
            greenLight = Template.FindName("EGreenLight", this) as Ellipse;

            UpdateLight();

            base.OnApplyTemplate();
        }


        public void UpdateLight()
        {

            switch (Value)
            {
                case "GESPERRT":
                    redLight.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                    redLight.Effect = new DropShadowEffect()
                    {
                        Color = new Color { A = 255, R = 255, G = 0, B = 0 },
                        BlurRadius = 3,
                        Direction = -90,
                        ShadowDepth = 0
                    };
                    break;

                case "IN BEARBEITUNG":
                    orangeLight.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkOrange);
                    orangeLight.Effect = new DropShadowEffect()
                    {
                        Color = new Color { A = 255, R = 255, G = 165, B = 255 },
                        BlurRadius = 3,
                        Direction = -90,
                        ShadowDepth = 0
                    };
                    break;

                case "FREIGEGEBEN":
                    greenLight.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                    greenLight.Effect = new DropShadowEffect()
                    {
                        Color = new Color { A = 255, R = 0, G = 255, B = 0 },
                        BlurRadius = 3,
                        Direction = -90,
                        ShadowDepth = 0
                    };
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Components/DLightSystemStyle.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:components="clr-namespace:Pruefprogramm.Components">


    <Style TargetType="components:CLightSystem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="components:CLightSystem">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="DimGray">
                            <Ellipse Height="20"
                                     Width="20"
                                     Fill="LightGray"
                                     x:Name="ERedLight"/>
                            <Ellipse Height="20"
                                     Width="20"
                                     Fill="LightGray"
                                     x:Name="EOrangeLight" />
                            <Ellipse Height="20"
                                     Width="20"
                                     Fill="LightGray"
                                     x:Name="EGreenLight" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Thank you very much
Levin

Comment: Are there any data binding error messages in the Output Window in Visual Studio when you run the application in debugger?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

DataTemplate is underlined with the message:

`Cannot locate resource 'components/dlightsystemstyle.xaml'.`

I have also attached the resource dictionary from the control

Answer (score 0):

If it works outside the `DataGrid` in the same parent control/window but not inside, it's probably the binding to `StatusDrawing` that fails.

If this property is defined in the same class as the `CncCollectionM12` property, you should bind to it like this:

```
<components:CLightSystem Value="{Binding DataContext.StatusDrawing, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
```